# Debug Page of Symfony 3.3.5 is loading infinitely

Tags: symfony

I can't manage to make my Synfony 3.3.5 project debug page work.

Here is what append:

1) I activate the "dev" mode : `$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);` in `app.php`

2) I try to load a page with an error (this error is not my issue. I created it on purpose)

3) The debug page start to load but continue to load infinitely without displaying the end of the debug page.
[image: screenshot step 3]

4) An error message from my browser appear.
[image: screenshot step 4]

And I must specify that this issue is only on my production environment.
In local, on my computer, it's working, just fine.
[image: screenshot step 3 that works fine on local environment]

Any ideas ?

Comment: Have you researched the error? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42168678/attempted-to-call-function-from-namespace-symfony-controller

Comment: My problem is not the "Attemp to call a function". I create on purpose a stupid code to have this error. My problem is that on my production environment I can't manage to have the debug page load correctly. I add a screenshot of my local environment in order to make you see the difference (because it's working juste fine in local).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried clearing your app cache? Or even your browser cache? I know my local environment gets hung up all the time because of cache issues.

Here is the command for prod environment cache clear:

```
php bin/console cache:clear --no-warmup -e prod
```

There is potential that the cache wherever your prod files reside is different than your local cache.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately Yes I have. Not with the command because I can't access the server to launch it: I'm hosted on 1&1. But I manually deleted /var/cache/prod. It didn't help.

Comment: Hm, I'm trying to think of anything else it could be. Can you run that command locally and then push it to the server? Also have you tried using a different debugger? I use xDebug with PHPStorm and it works quite well, but it depends on what IDE you use.

Comment: In fact, it's auto push to the server. So, I guess it's not the solution to my problem. I'd like not to use a different debugger. But maybe I would try this way if I do not manage to find the solution to my problem. Thanks for your answers!